# How to implement navigation activity and Recyclerview in MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I started off with a Navigation drawer activity and I added a recyclerView into the content_main.xml but I have been unable to implement the RecyclerView into the ManiActivity.java file.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

That is what my MainAcitity.java looks like when I haven't only implemented the NavigationView Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener {

MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // data to populate the RecyclerView with
    ArrayList<String> animalNames = new ArrayList<>();
    animalNames.add("Horse");
    animalNames.add("Cow");
    animalNames.add("Camel");
    animalNames.add("Sheep");
    animalNames.add("Goat");

    // set up the RecyclerView
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvAnimals);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, animalNames);
    adapter.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + adapter.getItem(position) + " on row number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

And I also need this(the recyclerview) into my MainActivity.java There isn't room for both

This code below is my adapter class and the whole struggle is to add this to the MainActivity.java

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<String> mData = Collections.emptyList();
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

// data is passed into the constructor
public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mData = data;
}

// inflates the row layout from xml when needed
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

// binds the data to the textview in each row
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String animal = mData.get(position);
    holder.myTextView.setText(animal);
}

// total number of rows
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}


// stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView myTextView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAnimalName);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

// convenience method for getting data at click position
public String getItem(int id) {
    return mData.get(id);
}

// allows clicks events to be caught
public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

// parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

}

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: I am not able to get your question, what is a main problem you are facing?

Comment: I can't add the adapter of the recycler view into the MainActivity.java file

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement both NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener and  MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener interfaces on the MainActivity class. This way you would be able to call the adapter class for the Recycler view.Your code should look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener {

  MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

// data to populate the RecyclerView with
ArrayList<String> animalNames = new ArrayList<>();
animalNames.add("Horse");
animalNames.add("Cow");
animalNames.add("Camel");
animalNames.add("Sheep");
animalNames.add("Goat");

// set up the RecyclerView
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvAnimals);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, animalNames);
adapter.setClickListener(this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}  

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + adapter.getItem(position) + " on row number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}
```

In Java, a class can implement more than one interfaces and a class can only extend from one parent. Implementation of more than one interfaces eliminates multiple inheritance which is not allowed in Java.

For example: 
ClassA implements ClassB, ClassC

Your edited code can be found [here](https://github.com/Ikhiloya/NavigationandRecyclerView)

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be associated with Adapter class. I would like to see your code for adapter.
1. Make sure if count is not equal to zero.
2. Make sure you are inflating a proper view in adapter class.
3. The view you are inflating must have external layout Relative or Linear or Constraint.

Comment: okay, how do I add the recycler view adapter into this existing MainActivity.java file

Comment: @DonaldOkaragba You need to show me your adapter class.

Comment: I have included my Adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

        TabLayout tabLayout;
        ViewPager viewPager;
        NavigationView navigationView;
        View navHeaderView;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

      Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
                drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
                toggle.syncState();



        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        navHeaderView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerContainer);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        textViewNavigationName = (TextView) 
        navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNavigationName);
        textViewNavigationEmail = (TextView) 
        navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNavigationEmail);


         FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
         FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
         fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
         Fragment_Home objFragment1 = new Fragment_Home();                    
         fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.viewPagerContainer, objFragment1).addToBackStack("backkkkkkkkkkkkk");

         fragmentTransaction.commit();

       }

  }
    public class Fragment_Home extends Fragment
    {
        private static final String ARG_PAGE_KEY = "arg_page";
            String nextPageToken;
            String prevPageToken;
            String pageToken;
            int sizeOfPlaylist;
            int sizeOfCurrentList;
            int firstItemPosition;

            MenuItem nextItem;
            MenuItem lastItem;


            LinearLayout linearLayoutProgress, linearLayoutNoConnection;
            Button buttonReload;
            RecyclerView recyclerViewVideos;
            AllVideosAdapterR adapter;
            TextView textViewProgress;

            public static Fragment_Home newInstance(int pageNumber) {
                Fragment_Home myFragment = new Fragment_Home();
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putInt(ARG_PAGE_KEY, pageNumber);
                myFragment.setArguments(arguments);
                return myFragment;
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                setHasOptionsMenu(true);
                LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View view = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

                findControls(view);

                gettingList();

                buttonReload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        gettingList();

                    }
                });

                return view;

            }


           public void findControls(View view)
           {
               recyclerViewVideos = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewVideos);
               linearLayoutProgress = (LinearLayout)view. findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutProgress);
               textViewProgress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewProgress);
               linearLayoutProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               linearLayoutNoConnection = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutNoConnection);
               linearLayoutNoConnection.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               buttonReload = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonReload);
           }

            private boolean isDeviceOnline() {
                ConnectivityManager connMgr =
                        (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
            }

            public void setAdapter(List<Item> listItems) {

                recyclerViewVideos.setLayoutManager(new 
                LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                adapter = new AllVideosAdapterR(getActivity(), listItems);
                recyclerViewVideos.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            public void showProgress(String message) {

                textViewProgress.setText(message);
                linearLayoutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }


            public void stopProgress() {

                linearLayoutProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            public void gettingList() {

                if (!isDeviceOnline()) {
                    linearLayoutNoConnection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    linearLayoutNoConnection.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                showProgress("Loading videos..");

                Retrofit retrofit = newRetrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BaseUrls.BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
                WebApis call1 = retrofit.create(WebApis.class);
                Call<ListResponse> call = call1.requestList();
                call.enqueue(new Callback<ListResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ListResponse> call, Response<ListResponse> response) {
                        System.out.println("size....................." + response.body().getItems().size());
                        setAdapter(response.body().getItems());
                        sizeOfPlaylist = response.body().getPageInfo().getTotalResults();

                        try {
                            nextPageToken = response.body().getNextPageToken();
                            prevPageToken = response.body().getPrevPageToken();
                            firstItemPosition = response.body().getItems().get(0).getSnippet().getPosition();
                            sizeOfCurrentList = response.body().getItems().size();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "More pages not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        stopProgress();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ListResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                        stopProgress();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Check your Network connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        linearLayoutNoConnection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });
            }

            public void gettingNextList(String token) {
                showProgress("Loading videos..");
                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BaseUrls.BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
                WebApis call1 = retrofit.create(WebApis.class);
                Call<ListResponse> call = call1.requestNextList(token);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<ListResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ListResponse> call, Response<ListResponse> response) {
                        System.out.println("size....................." + response.body().getItems().size());
                        setAdapter(response.body().getItems());
                        try {
                            nextPageToken = response.body().getNextPageToken();
                            prevPageToken = response.body().getPrevPageToken();
                            firstItemPosition = response.body().getItems().get(0).getSnippet().getPosition();
                            sizeOfCurrentList = response.body().getItems().size();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "More pages not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        stopProgress();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ListResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        stopProgress();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
            }  




 public interface WebApis {


                @GET(BaseUrls.GETTING_LIST)
                Call<ListResponse> requestList();

                @GET(BaseUrls.GETTING_LIST)
                Call<ListResponse> requestNextList(@Query("pageToken") String pageToken);


            }

        }
```

Comment: I used here viewPager, you can go out for FrameLayout. And it is better to have coding part of Recycler view in fragment. At last, you just need to attach fragment with frameLayout using FragmentManager.